# Plus[__] matches everything in MatchQ

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching

I understand that

```
Clear[a,b,c]
MatchQ[a+b+c, Plus[__]]
True
```

Because `a+b+c` is in fact `Plus[a,b,c]`, and the number of arguments in `Plus` is 3, which is bigger then `0`. So it fits for two continuous underlines (`__`) in `Plus`.

But I can't understand the followings:

```
MatchQ[abc, Plus[__]]
True

MatchQ["abc", Plus[__]]
True

MatchQ[a b c, Plus[__]]
True
```

`abc` is a just symbol, `a b c` is `Times[a,b,c]` and `"abc"` is a just string. Why does `MatchQ` gives `True` for these inputs?

I've been using Mathematica for long time...
The incomprehensible `True` makes me feel like I'm in a dream.

Comment: **abc is Times[a,b,c]**  no, it is not. space is important.  `a b c` is `Times[a,b,c]`, but `abc` is just a symbol

Comment: `abc` is not `Times[...]` but a variable. Try: `MatchQ["abc", Plus[__]] // Trace` to see the evaluation sequence.

Comment: @Nasser, I corrected the mistake in my question, but I still do not know yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a function doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute, its argument(s) will always be evaluated before going **into** the function. `MatchQ` is such a function, so `Plus[__]` evaluates first and becomes `__`. This can be checked with `Trace`:

```
MatchQ[abc, Plus[__]] // Trace
```

[image]

The standard way to stop the automatic calculation in this case is to use `HoldPattern`:

```
MatchQ[abc, HoldPattern@Plus[__]]
(* False *)
```

Alternatively:

```
MatchQ[abc, (h : Plus)[__]]
MatchQ[abc, __Plus]
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm quite weak in `Hold`, evaluation,... something very new at least for me.

Comment: @imidak Indeed, evaluation control is advanced topic in _Mathematica_. Just keep the line "If a function doesn't have a `Hold*` attribute, its argument(s) will always be evaluated before going **into** the function" in mind, you'll gradually get used to it :) .

Comment: Thank you again!