# Using Cases to select expressions from a list

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, core-language

I am using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. I want to use `Cases` to select the `Times` and `Plus` cases from the following list.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
expr = {2 a, 2 b, a + b, 2 c, a + c, b + c, 2 d, a + d, b + d, c + d};

expr // FullForm
```

> List[Times[2,a],Times[2,b],Plus[a,b],Times[2,c],Plus[a,c],Plus[b,c],Times[2,d],Plus[a,d],Plus[b,d],Plus[c,d]]

Cases 1/2/3 work fine.

**Case 1**

```
{Cases[expr, Plus[a_, b_], {1}], Cases[expr, Times[a_, b_], {1}]}
```

> {{a + b, a + c, b + c, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 d}}

**Case 2**

```
{Cases[expr, a_ + b_, {1}], Cases[expr, a_  b_, {1}]}
```

> {{a + b, a + c, b + c, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 d}}

**Case 3**

```
{Cases[expr, _Plus, {1}], Cases[expr, _Times, {1}]}
```

> {{a + b, a + c, b + c, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 d}}

**Case 4**

Using a `Blank` does not work.

```
{Cases[expr, Plus[_], {1}], Cases[expr, Times[_], {1}]}
```

> {{2 a, 2 b, a + b, 2 c, a + c, b + c, 2 d, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a,
> 2 b, a + b, 2 c, a + c, b + c, 2 d, a + d, b + d, c + d}}

**Case 5**

Using a `BlankSequence` does not work either.

```
{Cases[expr, Plus[__], {1}], Cases[expr, Times[__], {1}]}
```

> {{2 a, 2 b, a + b, 2 c, a + c, b + c, 2 d, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a,
> 2 b, a + b, 2 c, a + c, b + c, 2 d, a + d, b + d, c + d}}

**Case 6**

This is the most weird one. `Plus[_,_]` returns the multiplied terms and the `Times[_,_]` returns nothing

```
{Cases[expr, Plus[_, _], {1}], Cases[expr, Times[_, _], {1}]}
```

> {{2 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 d}, {}}

**Case 7**

Reintroducing one named pattern makes it work again. Making it two named patterns would get us back to Case 1.

```
{Cases[expr, Plus[x_, _], {1}], Cases[expr, Times[x_, _], {1}]}
```

> {{a + b, a + c, b + c, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 d}}

**Case 8**

This one works but i don't understand it.

```
{Cases[expr, Plus[_, __], {1}], Cases[expr, Times[_, __], {1}]}
```

> {{a + b, a + c, b + c, a + d, b + d, c + d}, {2 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 d}}

Can someone please help me understand this better? Thanks.

Comment: It's a matter of evaluation order. The analysis in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280488/1871 is fully applicable to your problem.

Comment: Some other strongly related posts: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280250/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124224/1871

Comment: Many thanks @xzczd. Evaluating these: `{Plus[_], Plus[__], Plus[_, _], Plus[_, __], Plus[a_, _]}` has helped clear the confusion. `Plus[_, _]` gets evaluated to `2 _` (Case 6) and coincidentally there were some `2 _` terms. Cases 4/5/6 were resolve with `HoldPattern`.